# I added a library directly to my src folder, Eclipse seems to be compiling properly, but can't find the class file?

Tags: java, eclipse, boilerpipe

I added the boilerpipe library directly to my src folder. Everything seems to be compiling when I run, but I get an error telling me that one of the classes in the boilerpipe library could not be resolved.

The ArticleExtractor class is what I'm trying to use, but Eclipse won't let me even though its class file is in the bin folder.

I'd post a picture, but I don't have the reputation. Boilerpipe itself is a folder containing several other folders, containing the .java files in the source folder, and .class files in the bin folder after I've tried to run. I couldn't find anything on this here so I though I'd ask.

Comment: Is it a jar you are using in your project or the source code?

Comment: @AnindaBhattacharyya No, It's all .java.

Comment: its better to use jar and paste it in `libs` folder

Comment: How you are running the code? Please paste your error and the details for better debugging.

Comment: How would I use jar instead? The error reads "java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: ArticleExtractor cannot be resolved". I'm running the code inside eclipse as a java application. I would give pictures, but I'm not allowed to.

Answer (score -1):

without seeing the code I would say that you either haven't added it to the build path or haven't imported the code into your class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is appears to be more like a comment than an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).  Please consider either editing this post into an answer or removing it.

Comment: There are no jar files, only .java files. I don't see any jar files that came with the download. Is there a way to get jars instead?

Comment: ok, in that case it's probably that you need to import the class in your code. It might throw additional errors based on how those .java files are written though, if they are importing code that isn't in your build path